# Processor Multi-threading

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, processor

If a program or application does not contain any threads; does the operating system automatically divide the job/process into multiple threads?

Example: if an application performs a simple task of completing random calculations and this specific application does not explicitly create its own threads to perform this calculation. Will the operating system automatically divide the process into multiple threads for the processor to compute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 'If a program or application does not contain any threads'

..it can do nothing because it has no execution.  All processes that are not in the state of being terminated have at least one thread - usually the one created by the loader to run code at the process entry point when the process is raised.

> if an application performs a simple task of completing random
>   calculations and this specific application does not explicitly create
>   its own threads to perform this calculation. Will the operating system
>   automatically divide the process into multiple threads for the
>   processor to compute?

No, not with any OS I know of.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the os, I think windows does not do that, but ubuntu does, correct me if I'm wrong anyone who knows for sure